# Python swf manipulation

Tags: python, xml, parsing, flash

I need some info about how to parse(transform), a .swf file to xml, manipulate some data, and reconstructed to a new .swf file.

Some python library or ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which data you want to update, but this tool can be usefull

http://www.swftools.org